# How to insert data in mongodb array using C#.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I have collection of Veh_info in mongodb having

```
id:1
color:red
Cly:4
Loc:{ Loc1
      Loc2
    }
```

I have created classes like

```
public class Car()
{ Public Objectid id {get;set;}
  public color {get;set;}
  public  Cly {get;set;}
  Public Location loc {get;set}
}
Public class Location()
{ public string loc{get;set;}
}
```

I have no idea how to insert new record i.e Loc3 in array in C# on Click event . If any one give some hits.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, collection Veh_info==Car?
if is that true, why Location type property in Car class is not array? You have errors in your class definition.

```
public class Car
{
   public ObjectId Id{get;set;}
   public string Color{get;set;}
   public int Cly{get;set;}
   public List<Location>Locs{get;set;}
}
```

than you can use this code:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var server = client.GetServer();
var db = server.GetDatabase("MyDbName");
var collection=db.GetCollection<Car>("Veh_info");
Car carById= collection.Find(Query<Car>.EQ(x=>x.Id,1));
if(carById!=null)
  carById.Locs.Add(new Location(){loc="my new location name"});
collection.Save(carById);
```