# Reading from API and updating MongoDB

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, api

I'm new to the use of MongoDB and I have an assignment where I need to call an API and update a MongoDB with the results from that API.

I've written some jQuery AJAX-calls to the API and they work just fine, but what is the best practice, in your opinion, to then post this to the MongoDB?

The task I've received includes creating the queries and the logic to also update the new or changed information to the Mongo database.

Answer (score 0):

I am using nodejs, mongoose with mongodb. i created a funciton in which three parameters first is connected db and second is your api doc and then callback function.

```
exports.insert = function(db, doc, callback) {
 // TODO: implement
  console.log(doc);
 db.collection("movies").insert(doc,function(error,result){
    if(error){
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
}
});
 callback(null);
};
```

i hope it helps you

Comment: thanks for you reply, i guess db takes a variable that holds the database-uri, doc holds the api-uri? what is exports holding? sorry if the questions are bad, i'm new to mongodb.

Comment: which language you are using in server side with mongodb? i used nodejs

Comment: its a asp.net mvc-application

Comment: ok then you try with this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896536/how-to-insert-data-in-mongodb-array-using-c-net

Comment: thanks a lot, that seems helpful. but it doesn't really solve my problem with the api. i need to first query the api to check for updates and then update the mongoDB. the api is to another database, naturally. how would i get the latest update from the api and then put that into the DB in MVC? thanks